# Can I use another calendar in a Space Opera?

Tags: science-fiction, space

I'm creating a space opera (or a soft science fiction in space) universe, but I am trying to devise a calendar and I don't know if I should use the calendar of Earth (using the time before and after of Christ) or a fictional calendar (using another dates).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Daniel. I've made a few grammatical edits to your question, but I wasn't quite sure what you were intending. If you disagree, feel free to roll them back. In the meantime, could you clarify what the difference is between Earth's timeline with fiction, and a fictional timeline of Earth? Consider [edit]ing your post to include this clarification. Also, feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986) to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: I am afraid that "Can I do X?" is inherently opinion based. It's your story, you do what you want with it. Please try rephrasing the question to something more objectively answerable.

Comment: It sounds to me that you may be asking if you can use a different calendar or at least a different count of years, counting the years from a different point in time.  There are many different calendars and year counts on Earth already, counting the years from many different starting dates.  There were a few times in the 20th century when a country changed its calendar and natives could joke that they were suddenly over a thousand years older or younger.  Many space operas use fictional calendars.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** It's your story, you can do whatever you like!

Unless this is meant to be a historically accurate recounting of actual events, then you can change as little or as much as you like.  It's fiction, so you can choose to have it almost exactly the same as reality with a couple of things changing, or you can choose to have it completely unlike reality, both with respect to history or to physics.

It can be based on real events, but the explanations can be supernatural or science fiction or real events can be altered in any way that helps progress your story.

You have already indicated that it's meant to be soft science fiction, which gives you as much latitude as you need to change reality in whatever way suits your story best :)